# Javascript Connect 4 game, checking a winner

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Connect 4 game using Javascript.
So I began trying to search the horizontal for 4 in a row and made up this:

```
for (var y = 0; y < Column - 1; y++)
  for (var x = 0; x < Row - 1; x++)
    if (myArray1[y][x] == 1){
           Win1++;
           if (Win1 == 4){
              alert("Won");
              }
        } else {Win1 = 0}
```

I got it working when only checking 1 row, but when I added a second for loop to also check the columns it stopped working.

My intention is to run this (And code for checking vertical and diagonal) everytime I place down a piece.

Comment: I believe you need to reset `Win1` to zero for every column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @LuanNico in the comments, you need to reset your counter variable `Win1` before each row or column.

If your `Column` and `Row` variables hold the number of columns and rows, you might also have a one-off error by stopping your loop iteration one row or column too early.

I recommend to fix and reorganize your code a little bit as follows:

```js
function checkColums(board, columns, rows) {
  for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
    var consecutive = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
      if (board[y][x] == 1) {
        consecutive++;
        if (consecutive == 4) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function checkRows(board, columns, rows) {
  for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    var consecutive = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
      if (board[y][x] == 1) {
        consecutive++;
        if (consecutive == 4) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Example:
var board = [
  [1, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0]
];

console.log(checkColums(board, 4, 4)); // false
console.log(checkRows(board, 4, 4));   //  true
```